# How to mock class which uses Map Struct in Java?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, mapstruct

Java class which uses MAPSTRUCT we have static variable INSTANCE inside interface and this interface implementation is created at runtime.So, how to mock class which uses Map Struct in Java?

```
    @Mapper 1
    public interface CarMapper {

        CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class ); 3

        @Mapping(source = "numberOfSeats", target = "seatCount")
        CarDto carToCarDto(Car car); 2
    }


    public class A
    {
        public CarDto getCardto()
        {
            CarDto carDto = CarMapper.INSTANCE.carToCarDto(car);
            return carDto;
        }

    }
```

How to create mock for class A?

Comment: Please give some code to look at, your description is not anywhere near adequate. Also "MAPSTRUCT" is not anything that I know of; another reason to include some code.

Comment: If you are using the static variable `INSTANCE` that means that you are using the default `componentModel`. Why would you need to mock such a class? You don't have to use a static variable in the interface, you can also create it on another place (the place where you need it).

Comment: Can you look at the code?

Comment: First of all MapStruct is an annotation processor and thus it creates the implementation classes at compile time, not runtime. Looking at the code my answer is still valid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock class `A` then you can just do `Mockito.mock(A.class)`.

Comment: That i know,
When mocking CarMapper.INSTANCE, 
it throws ClassNotFoundException, since we don't have any CarMapperImpl it got generated at runtime.

Comment: Why do you need to mock CarMapper.INSTANCE? Mocking class A means overriding `getCardto()` completely, so there's no need to worry about the INSTANCE object.

Comment: Again the `CarMapperImpl` is generated at compile time, not runtime. The comment from Ray is valid. How does the `INSTANCE` object interfere with the mocking of `A`?